# Showing the count of rows in a MySQL table, where the logged events are exactly x year and y month old

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, where-clause

I have a quite simple database which autologs events and dates. I've recently tried looking at how many events took place exactly x years and y month ago. I know this can be acommplished by manually looking up
the date and making a where year(time) = x and month(time)=y, but is there an option to do this with timediff or datesub somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how many events took place exactly x years and y month ago

I think that you want:

```
select *
from mytable 
where 
    mydate >= current_date - interval X year - interval Y month
    and mydate < current_date - interval X year - interval Y month + interval 1 day
```

This gives you the events that occured within the entire day `X` year and `Y` months ago (which you need to replace with the relevant integer values), using MySQL date arithmetics.

Comment: Isn't this more complex than my answer but doing the same thing? (legit asking)

Comment: @Mech: I think OP's point is to actually generate the dates from the "year/month ago" specification.

Comment: Your answer is on point for the request, it's just so much more work then putting in the date you want to start with :P

Comment: @GMB Yeah, sorry for the chaotic explanation, but that's exactly what i meant and what i needed.

Comment: @Mech Yeah, i know, it would be far easier to put in the exact date, but the requirements were to show events from x years and y month, which is already strange.

Comment: @Mech: well that's quite standard date math, nothing fancy. If OP were to generate the dates from their application, that would not necessarily easier.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your query:

```
WHERE `date` BETWEEN date1 AND NOW()
```

or

```
WHERE `date` >= date1
```